# Can not install scipy using pip

Tags: python, scipy, pip

I am trying to install scipy using pip, but I get errors:
**

```
C:\Users\Vikram>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import set
uptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\VIKRAM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build
-3uik7cbv\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.r
ead().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" ins
tall --record C:\Users\VIKRAM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-cvzvs2ed-record\install-r
ecord.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
```

**any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you're on Windows you need to know about http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

Comment: Yes trying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following, Download the scipy file correspoding to your python version and your processor(32/64 bit) from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Download the version of numpy+mkl (needed to run scipy). now you can migrate to your scripts folder present inside the python folder and try installing those .whl files there. To install just open command window there by pressing right_click while holding down shift key.

Then enter `pip install`  and drag the .whl files to the cmd window it should install. Check the installation by opening idle and checking by `import` command.
 Hope this helps.